# What is the difference between const T * and T * const?

Tags: c++, c, constants

For a given type `T`:

What is the difference between `const T *` and `T * const`?

Also, are there other places that `const` can go? For instance, is `T const *` a thing? Can you have more than one `const` in an expression, such as `const T * const`?

Comment: Use the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) and it should be a lot clearer what the difference is and that it can go "before" anything it can apply to.

Answer (score 7):

`const T *x` means `x` points to an object of type `T`, but that object should not be modified.

On the other hand, `T *const x` means the pointer *itself* cannot be modified (but the object it points to *can*).

`const T *const x` is just a combination of the two; both the pointer and the object it points to cannot be modified.

Comment: [detailed information in the faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html)